# How to parse Wikipedia JSON Dictionary with Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, wikipedia-api

I'm new to the Wikipedia API and I have been trying to parse the image url from the API. The JSON I'm trying to parse is as follows:

API:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=tokyo&prop=pageimages&format=json

JSON Result:

```
{"batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "tokyo",
        "to": "Tokyo"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "30057": {
        "pageid": 30057,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Tokyo",
        "thumbnail": {
          "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg/50px-Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg",
          "width": 50,
          "height": 27
        },
        "pageimage": "Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the struct I created to parse the data. I can see the url when I print it to the console, but since "source" is nested under "thumbnail", which lives in the value of the [String:Page] dict pair, I can't figure out a way to access it. How do I parse data in a dictionary like this? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
struct WikiAPIResults: Codable {
  let batchcomplete: String?
  let query: Query?
}

struct Query: Codable {
  let normalized: [Normalized]?
  let pages: [String:Pages]? // <- I can get to here
}

struct Normalized: Codable {
  let from, to: String? 
}

struct Pages: Codable {
  let pageid, ns: Int?
  let title: String?
  let thumbnail: Thumbnail?
  let pageimage: String?
}

struct Thumbnail: Codable {
  let source: String? // <- But I want to grab this
  let width, height: Int?
}

func fetchImageFromWikipedia(imageKeyword: String, completion: @escaping (WikiAPIResults) -> Void) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?")!
    urlComponents.queryItems = [
    "action": "query",
    "titles": imageKeyword,
    "prop": "pageimages",
    "format": "json"].map { URLQueryItem(name: $0.key, value: $0.value) }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlComponents.url!) { data, response, error in
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let data = data,
           let result = try? jsonDecoder.decode(WikiAPIResults.self, from: data) {
            completion(result)
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}

fetchImageFromWikipedia(imageKeyword: "Tokyo") { result in
    print(result.query?.pages?.values)
}
```

Comment: I think you also have to correct your Page struct names.

Comment: can you add to your post both the command you're using to print to the console as well as the the result of what is displayed to you on the console? This will help better understand what your issue is, because from what you wrote, it seems you do have access to the source property within the `Thumbnail` object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean gathering all thumbnail sources?

```
fetchImageFromWikipedia(imageKeyword: "Tokyo") { result in
    let pages = result.query?.pages?.compactMap { $0.value } ?? []
    let thumbnailSources = pages.compactMap { $0.thumbnail?.source }
    print(thumbnailSources)
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This works with your example perfectly:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Response: Decodable {

    struct Query: Decodable {

        struct NormalizedQuery: Decodable {

            let from: String
            let to: String

        }

        struct Page: Decodable {

            struct Thumbnail: Decodable {

                let source: URL
                let width: Int
                let height: Int

            }

            let id: Int
            let ns: Int
            let title: String
            let thumbnail: Thumbnail
            let pageImage: String

            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

                case id = "pageid"
                case ns
                case title
                case thumbnail
                case pageImage = "pageimage"

            }

        }

        let normalized: [NormalizedQuery]
        let pages: [String : Page]

    }

    let batchComplete: String
    let query: Query

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case batchComplete = "batchcomplete"
        case query

    }

}

let responseString = """
{
    "batchcomplete" : "",
    "query" : {
        "normalized" : [
            {
                "from" : "tokyo",
                "to" : "Tokyo"
            }
        ],
        "pages" : {
            "30057" : {
                "pageid" : 30057,
                "ns" : 0,
                "title" : "Tokyo",
                "thumbnail" : {
                    "source" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg/50px-Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg",
                    "width" : 50,
                    "height" : 27
                },
                "pageimage" : "Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}
"""
let responseData = responseString.data(using: .utf8)!

let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: responseData)
print(response)
// Response(batchComplete: "", query: __lldb_expr_18.Response.Query(normalized: [__lldb_expr_18.Response.Query.NormalizedQuery(from: "tokyo", to: "Tokyo")], pages: ["30057": __lldb_expr_18.Response.Query.Page(id: 30057, ns: 0, title: "Tokyo", thumbnail: __lldb_expr_18.Response.Query.Page.Thumbnail(source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg/50px-Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg, width: 50, height: 27), pageImage: "Skyscrapers_of_Shinjuku_2009_January.jpg")]))
```